# NetSuite Workflow for freezing a number (on document creation)

Tags: netsuite, crm

My company is currently trying to find a way to freeze a number in the transaction line of sales orders.

essentially, we have a {quantity} in the transaction line to represent how much of item x is in a specific sales order. However, we often edit that number after the fact once we've figured out how much we are capable of fulfilling. The issue arrises as we often go and edit that initial {quantity} field to represent what we are actually capable of fulfilling, yet we would like to hold onto that number for our own sake of comparing and seeing our fulfilment success rate.

So now I'm here as I'm unable to create a tline field that will allow the initial {quantity} value to flow into a new field (SOLELY on Sales Order creation, not on later edits) and freezes it as is.

I've been playing around with workflows but I'm struggling to bring this idea to the platform.

Any guidance would be great!

So now I'm here as I'm unable to create a tline field that will allow the initial {quantity} value to flow into a new field (SOLELY on Sales Order creation, not on later edits) and freezes it as is.

Comment: You've more-or-less outlined the obvious approach (create custom transaction line field, create workflow to copy from the native Quantity field into that custom field with the workflow set to run on create only).  So what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Another approach would be to fulfill what you can, and then close the order (after it's invoiced) if you're unable to fulfill the rest.  Then you retain the original quantity in the `{quantity}` field and the fulfilled quantity will be in the `{quantityfulfilled}` field.

Comment: @Krypton my issue sadly is with setting the transaction line field as a target, unfortunately I am unable to select it.

Comment: Are you familiar with *[line level workflows](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/sw18/sess/1516756700508001QblW/PF/SES1513-OPS%20-%20Line-Level%20Workflows_15245979526490017UE5.pptx)?*

Comment: @Krypton unfortunately no! but I'll make sure to look into it :)